# Migrating record types in org-to-org Gearset migration

Tags: record-type, migration

I am receiving this error from Gearset:

`Record types with picklists definitions where the corresponding field definition could not be located.`

where Gearset is instructing me to:

`Remove picklist definitions that do not have corresponding field definitions from record type.`

Then a number of record types of different objects are listed. These record types list a number of "Picklists Available for Editing", all of which are indeed defined fields on the corresponding objects. Anyone know what could be going on here?

Comment: Does Gearset specify the field? Is it possible to get a little bit more of the log?

Comment: They are simply custom record types on standard objects, where the error prints the record type in the form, e.g.: `Contact.Custom_Contact_Type`. The only additional log information is the elaboration: `Some record types have definitions for picklists that are not otherwise referenced by the custom object they belong to - this is often because a picklist field was deleted on the source side and the record type was not updated. These record types should be modified to remove these definitions or the deployment will fail.`

Comment: You will have to examine the xml of the record types and determine what picklist value it is referring to. Please post the xml of the object and record types so that we can take a closer look.